# How do I bind a jQuery Tools overlay event to an existing overlay?

Tags: jquery, events, overlay, bind

Say when the page loads, this code runs:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('#overlay').overlay( api: true );
});
```

How would I bind an event to it? I've tried:

```
$('#overlay').onBeforeLoad( function(){ alert('Hi'); });

$('#overlay').bind( 'onBeforeLoad', function(){ alert('Hi'); });

var api = $('#overlay').data('overlay');
api.onBeforeLoad(function(){ alert('Hi') });
```

When I do:

```
alert(api.getContent().attr('id'));
```

An alert pops up with '#overlay' inside.

When the overlay is open and I run:

```
alert(api.isOpened());
```

An alert pops up with 'false' inside.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The overlay is working fine so I don't think any existing code is an issue. I need to be able to bind the onBeforeLoad event no matter what the configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var api = $('#overlay').data('overlay');  
api.onBeforeLoad = function() {
    console.log('Hi');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('#overlay').overlay({ 
   onBeforeLoad: function(){ 
      alert('Hi');
   }
});
```

**edit**

I see, I think your problem starts here.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('#overlay').overlay( api: true );
});
```

should be this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      $('#overlay').overlay();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var api = $("#overlay").overlay({api: true});  
api.load();
```